# Is it possible to show a path between two annotations using the MapKit API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mapkit, cllocation

I am working on an app that will show the user the closest locations from a database to the user.  When the user selects one of these locations from a list, the user will then see a map on a new screen showing an annotation representing the user, and another annotation representing the location.

Is it possible using the MapKit API to show the user a path from the user to the location?  I am not asking about how to show turn by turn directions.  I just want to display a path between the two annotations.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 4.x, Apple added support for map overlays. It might help to read a little bit more about the `MKPolyline` & `MKPolylineView` classes and the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method defined in the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. All available in the [Map Kit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html).